# Media images not showing, even though they successfully load on the page

Tags: python, django

Uploaded images from users are stored in the `media` folder, like most Django apps. However for some reason they stopped showing after I made a few changes in my app. The weird thing is, when I click inspect element on the image div, it shows the img src and it's correct. When I hover over the img src: `<img src="/media/REC-2.jpg">`, it just says 'Could not load the image'. Keep in mind, all of my static files show fine. Just the media images, (images that are uploaded through a user `Post`), arn't showing.

There's also a weird thing in my view that could indicate what the problem is. Here's my code:

choices.py

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'news'),
    ('2', 'sport'),
    ('3', 'technology'),
)
```

urls

```
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/', boxes_view, name='bv'),
```

views

```
def boxes_view(request, category):
    print('initial', category)

    for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        if b == category:
            category = a

    print('category', category)

    posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
    for post in posts:
        print('POST', post.id)

    return render(request, 'boxes.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Here's what comes up in my terminal after loading the page (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/`):

```
initial news
category 1
POST 1
POST 2
...
POST 241
POST 242
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:33] "GET /news/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19661
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
initial media
initial media
category media
initial media
category media
initial media
initial media
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /static/images/settingsIcon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
category media
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /media/465054_3137058941780_869886704_o_o8zCskP.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6370
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /static/images/trtLogo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
category media
category media
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /media/REC-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6370
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /static/images/mapIcon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /static/js/base.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /media/htcStory_xoFbTkY.JPG HTTP/1.1" 200 6370
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /media/34_comparison.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6370
[09/Mar/2017 23:39:34] "GET /media/REC_aeXxNPK.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6370
```

What's happening here? The first few lines are correct, it prints `initial news`, then `category 1` after going through the for loop, then it goes through each `Post`. Then it goes all weird. It goes back to the first print statements and prints `initial media` and `category media` many times. And inbetween these prints it loads the media images. Any idea what's going on and how I can fix it?

Edit: Full urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^more/$', more, name='more'),
    url(r'^q/', search, name='search'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^post/', include('post.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    url(r'^profile/(?P<user>\w+)/', profile, name='profile'),

    #category
    url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/', article, name='article'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/', boxes_view, name='bv'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'draft1/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: I don't think this will solve your media problem, but you've forgotten to add `$` at the end of most of your urls which means you may end up with some unexpected behaviour. The urls that you are importing from other modules don't need it, but you'll most likely want to put it on your urls named `profile`, `article`, and `bv`.

Comment: It doesn't solve it, but when I add a `$` at the end of `bv`, all the media image requests change from `"GET /news/media/htcStory_xoFbTkY.JPG HTTP/1.1" 200 19616` to `"GET /news/media/htcStory_xoFbTkY.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 4923`. If I don't add `$` then the GET for media all have the same number after 200, whereas adding `$` will give me a different number for each image after 404.

Comment: ok so I think there were two problems - this one was masking the true problem with the media files, which is they're not being served at that address. What was happening before was that requests to `/media/` were being routed to the `boxes_view` and returning nothing. You can now debug the media files issue more effectively.

Comment: Actually adding `$` does solve the problem, my mistake. I changed my `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` in settings to `MEDIA_URL = 'media/'` as @Julien suggested. But i've switched it back now and `$` does indeed solve it. Thankyou so much for the help. Can you explain to me why excluding `$` causes problems?

Comment: Great to hear! `$` is the regex code for 'end of regex'. If you neglect to add $, the regex parser just keeps looking for a match. So in your case, every url that did not match one of the preceding listed url patterns was successfully matched to your `boxes_view`, because `'^(?P<category>\w+)` is a very broad expression. Therefore requests to `/media/whatever.jpg` where being routed to `boxes_view`. In this case if I'd read your terminal output a little more carefully I should have picked that up earlier - the print statements from `boxes_view` were being called with 'media' as the category.

Comment: Yeah I can see what was happening with the print statements now, I'll make sure to add the `$` to narrow my url matches. Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't look like it's here, but in your image upload code. Since every `jpg` has the same size (`6370`) and every `png` has size `0`, there is something wrong with how you're serving the images.

In fact, everything request besides the initial `GET /news/` seems to be failing. Responses from requests to `/static/` all have size `0` and responses from requests to `/media/` all have size `6370`.

Comment: How could I see if there's a problem with serving my images? Also all the static files are working and showing fine, even though it says 0 (not sure what that means).

Comment: See what those 6370 bytes are that your app is serving for the `jpg` files. Open the Chrome network tab, click a request to the `jpg` resource, and preview the response.

Comment: All the media images say 'This request has no response data available`. They also have no preview available.

Comment: What happens when you visit those media URLs directly?

Comment: When I click on the url directly the page loads my template `boxes.html` (empty, with no queryset in it). url bar shows: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/htcStory_xoFbTkY.JPG`

Comment: What does your `urls.py` look like?

Comment: Media/static settings and full urls.py added in edit

Comment: Try setting `MEDIA_URL` to `media/` instead of `/media/`

Comment: Doesn't do anything to the page, but the terminal response is about 5 times longer as it goes through the for loop atleast 5 times. Still does does that weird thing by printing `initial media` and `category media`.